# Visual Studio 2010 crashes at successful build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, crash-dumps

Upon building my C++ projects vs2010 crashes even though the process was successful, I tried updating to Sp1 to see if that would fix the problem. But was stopped by some errors on installation. I tried to re-install, safemode, I had some addins about 3, AnkHSVN and two basic other and deleted them but experienced the same problem.

Specs:

OS: windows 7 64

VS: 2010 U

Comment: Post the log here, often those code-paste sites are blocked to many people (eg. me)

Comment: I'm having the same problem with C++ projects. I did a full uninstall of VS 2010 Pro, and installed VS 2010 C++ Express and its still crashing. I'm also on Windows 7 64bit. I've filed a bug report to microsoft connect, but they haven't gotten back to me yet. I'll let you know if I figure anything out

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution.

To fix: click start, type "cmd" into the search box, right click "cmd.exe" in the search results, select "run as admin", then run this command: regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"

Reference: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533194/crash-while-compile-an-extremely-simple-c-project

If that doesn't work, AnkHSVN is known to cause the same problem. You said you uninstalled it, but you may want to check out this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/05/11/if-you-are-seeing-intermittent-crashes-with-vs-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As a test, get out of visual studio.  Rename the **.suo** file in your solution directory.  Go back into visual studio and rebuild all.